# How to position to the left of text

Tags: css, html, position

I have searched for an answer to my question but haven't found one; or maybe I did but just to "green" to know it. I have tried webdesign.about.com/positionins, So You Want Positioning, Huh(HTML Goodies) I want to position an image to the left of my text. Do I need a div for the image? Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>Image Practice</title>

    <link href="css/final-practice.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
    <h1> This is an image example.</h1>
    <body>

        <p class="description">This is an example of an image stuck in the middle of HTML paragraph tags of type. <span>&#40See ppt-images-color.pdf in folder Downloads>lecture-01.&#41</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software</p>
        <p img class="wrap-right" src="images/blank-square.png" alt="Example of an image in middle of text" /p>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

body { 
    font-size: 76%; 
    background-color: #ffc;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #000;

}
p {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    clear:both;
}

span{
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#780000;
    }

p.wrap-right {
              position:relative;    
              float:left;
              width:32px;
              height:32px;
}
```

Comment: You really should read some introduction to html and css

Comment: The image is in a separate paragraph tag (<p>).  Think about it, you have your image in the paragraph following your text paragraph.  Where would you expect it to be?  If you want your image to the left of your text (i.e. before the text), simply put it before the text in the markup.

Comment: And Kai is correct... You shoudl go to http://www.w3schools.com/ and go through the html and css tutorials there.  It does not take too long and would really help.  Just friendly advise.

Comment: Don't recommend w3schools (http://w3fools.com)

Comment: Why? Its great for beginners.  And if you have a better suggestion, offer it.  Don't flame others.

Comment: @sn3ll why? is explained in the page i link ... and better suggestions for consult specific properties go direct to http://W3.org and many tutos and courses on http://net.tutsplus.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First at all you have invalid Html here :

```
<p img class="wrap-right" src="images/blank-square.png" alt="Example of an image in middle of text" /p>
```

It must be :

```
<p> 
<img class="wrap-right" src="images/blank-square.png" alt="Example of an image in middle of text"/>
</p>
```

And to make the image inside `p` go to the left try this on your CSS:

```
p {
 text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: I apologize for replying here. Thank you Danko and Tim and all who gave suggestions. This worked for me. Thanks again.

Comment: Np mate we are here to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your image tag isn't valid in your code snippet.

You have: `<p img`

It should be `<p><img`